# How to put notes for packages in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I saw for some packages IntelliJ shows the package name as

something **[some-notes]**

and I am wondering how I can set up the bold part in IntelliJ, since they seem very useful when we need some explanation of what the package does. Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: Are these maven packages?

Comment: yes they are maven pkgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bold **[some-notes]** that you are seeing is "Name" of the module according to IntelliJ. If the "Name" and the `artifactId` of the modules are the same then the bold addition will not appear. I do not believe this is meant for notes, but if you would like to have some appear there do the following:

1. [Access the Module Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-module-settings.html) for the package you would like to edit. E.g., `services-support`
   [image: Selecting a module to edit.]
2. Insert the notes into the "Name" field for the module.
   [image: Changing a module's name.]

The package should now appear with your notes in bold.
[image: Package with bold notes.]

*Note: This only applies to the module package level. Supplying a README or other form of documentation file is likely a better solution.*